# Insert trigger if row exists then update and don't insert

Tags: sql-server

Is there possibility to create insert trigger that checks before insert if row exist and if exist then updates ?

Comment: `Merge` should be your first option.

Comment: You could do that but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Why you don't recomend that?

Comment: Triggers in general should be used very rarely. They make debugging somewhat challenging and they are all too often not written correctly. I would suggest putting that same logic in your insert procedure instead of a trigger.

Comment: Here is an interesting article about MERGE. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: I don't understand how can i abort the insert?

Comment: I agree with Sean Lange - we've had problems with deadlocks on a certain table with heavy writes that had similar functionality.

Comment: You would have to do it as an instead of trigger...yuck